# What happens if a user enters some php code into input?

Tags: php, mysql, security, code-injection

Strings can be escaped in php before inserting them into database. But what happens, if an user of my website enters a php code?

For eg. An user submits the following to a form, which escapes the string and inserts the data into my database.

`Hello! <?php echo 'this is evil'; ?>'`

Then this php line will be stored in the database. And when I display the content, it will be converted into this :

`<div>Hello!<?php echo 'this is evil'?></div>`

Isn't this a potential security risk? As the php code can be very malicious?

Does this mean I have to use `strip_tags` on every user input?

Comment: You should sanitize user input no matter what, but no, that would not run. I'd replace `<>` with their respective `html_entities` however.

Comment: Should I use `htmlspecialchars` when displaying the content?
Also, why won't the above php code work? It should echo correctly if I echo the content to a div right?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. The php code gets echoed, so it won't be interpreted.

Comment: PHP cannot be nested. `<?php echo "<?php echo 'foo' ?>" ?>` will output `<?php echo 'foo' ?>`, not `foo`.

Comment: @MarcB Yes I got that bit, but now I don't know which answer to accept as they're all almost the same lol

Comment: Have a look at [my answer to *Preventing code injection without limiting user input?*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23501225/53114)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No It's not risky since php does not interpret the code and actually you don't use `eval` for this values so it will be shown as a plain text.

Now the thing is you should validate user's inputs. for example if this is an input for firstname, no one's name contains < or ?. so you can use Regexp to validate values.

Or you should print `htmlentities` of the value instead of raw value.

Comment: I see. So the php code does not get interpreted because it's being echoed right? Just like when we echo html code?
I use the `&` prefix for some functions on my website. I hope htmlentities will not remove that?

Comment: 1. Yes. It's just like echoing HTML.
2. It will transform `&` to `&amp;`

Answer (score -1):

That PHP code won't run but you have to validate userr form data before submitting it in database

replace all "<" and ">"  to `&lt` and `&gt` respectivly

```
$data = str_replace("<","&lt",$data);
$data = str_replace(">","&gt",$data);
```

this also help if user try to insert some javascript into  your code

Comment: @user3091574 I can just use `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` for that purpose.

Answer (score -1):

you have to add anti injection function, such as `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or `htmlspecialchars()` or `addslashes()` to your data that have submited by users

Comment: I have done that since the starting. I was just confused whether php code will work in it.

Comment: -1, **NO!** `mysqi_real_escape_string` and `htmlspecialchars` are **not** the same thing and [should be used only in the correct area of your code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3126175/168868).